# How to jsonify a picture in Flask

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a simple API using Flask, in which I now want to read some gif pictures. What do I need to do to make this serializable as JSON?

Here is my naive code :

```
def getfile(filename):
    file = request.files['file']
    return file.read()

@namespace.route('/get_image')
class Getpicture(DecoratedResource):
    @staticmethod 
    def get():
        if request.args.get('type') == '1':
           filename = 'ok.gif'
        else:
            filename = 'error.gif'
        file = getfile(filename)
        return  jsonify(file, mimetype='image/gif')
```

Results in:

{
  "message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
}

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to encode the image into a base64 string and then supply that into a json, this way you only pass a string as opposed to trying to convert an image into json

```
import base64

with open("yourfile.ext", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```